# Delegated event binding in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.myClass', function(){
       // ...
   });
});
```

Also this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', '.myClass', function(){
       // ...
   });
});
```

Only this works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.myClass').click(function(){
       // ...
   });
});
```

But I need to bind every time for dynamic event handling.
So please, can you explain why the first two don't work?

(Note: it doesn't work with `$('.delegetor')` neither (i.e. a wrapper div) I tried `body` and `document` just to make sure the delegator is static)

**EDIT**

From what I understood from the first answer:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grandchild">The one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I do

```
$('#child').click(function(){return false;});
$('#parent').on('click', '#grandchild', function(){ alert("hi");});
```

The click event won't reach grandchild because it stops in child ? (I don't think I understood this right)

Comment: Do you have any other click handlers that call `event.stopPropagation()`? That's the only thing I know of that interferes with delegation.

Comment: Barmar has a good guess. The way to find out is to do document on click and console.log it. If the click is hitting log the event and check the target to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: If I have another function bound to the event onClick with stopPropagation(), then why .click(function(){}) works?

Comment: Also note that in jQuery event handlers, `return false` also stops propagation of events, so you should check for that in `click` handlers as well (only jQuery).

Comment: They work so add all the code in your Q -- https://jsfiddle.net/5rqp08mf/   --- https://jsfiddle.net/63c3nw3b/

Comment: I don't have anything that uses .myClass in all my project files. So no I don't stop event propagation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation works by adding the event listener to the static container element that you bind the event to. It depends on the event bubbling up from the target element to the container element. When the container element receives the event, jQuery checks whether the target matches the selector, and then executes the callback function.

If you have a handler for an element that's between the target and the container, and it calls `event.stopPropagation()`, that stops the event from bubbling any further. So the event never reaches the container, and the delegation fails.

Note that if a jQuery event handler returns `false`, it's equivalent to calling:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

If you only need to do one or the other, you should do it explicitly in the handler, rather than returning `false`.

You need to bind the event to a static element as close in the DOM hierarchy as possible to the target element, and ensure that you don't have any intervening elements with click handlers that stop propagation.

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

isn't affected by this because it adds the event listener directly to the `.myClass` elements, not a container. So it doesn't depend on the event bubbling to a container element. There *would* be a problem if `.myClass` had a child with a click handler that stops propagation -- when you click on that child, `.myClass` wouldn't get the event. Event delegation would also be blocked by this.

Note that if a jQuery event handler returns `false`, it's equivalent to calling:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

So in your example, since you `return false` in the `#child` handler, it prevents the event from bubbling out to `#parent`, so the event delegation from `#parent` to `#grandchild` fails.

If you only need to do one or the other, you should do it explicitly in the handler, rather than returning `false`.

You would need to change your design to something like:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="intermediary">
        <div id="grandchild">The one</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you could do:

```
$("#intermediary").on("click", ".grandchild", function() {
    ...
});
```

This would not be affected by the `#child` handler.

Comment: Please look at my edit, because I couldn't explain what I understood from your answer in a comment. Thank you

Comment: (Isn't the propagation of the event starts from the inner element to the outer elements ?)

Comment: That's correct. So the event is triggered when you click on `#grandchild`. Then it bubbles out to `#child`, which stops the propagation by returning `false`. So it never bubbles out to `#parent`.

Comment: Thank you. In deed, I replaced `return false;` with `event.preventDefault();` and now it works.
I didn't know the event propagates from outer to inner. Thank you so much