# Why is my html table ignoring clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I've got an html table like so:

```
<table id="top10ItemsTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Item Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="rightjustifytext">Qty</th>
    </tr>
    . . .
```

I want to respond to clicks inside that table, and so added this to the ready function:

```
$("body").on("click", "#top10ItemsTable", function () {
    alert('you clicked inside the Top 10 Items quadrant table');
});
```

...but clicking the html table produces no alert, unless it is either microscopic or invisible.

What is needed to poke the table hard enough to get its dander up?

Comment: Looks to be working just fine https://jsfiddle.net/rb1hyxh2/19/

Comment: Do you have a click handler on any of the elements that contains the table? Does that handler use `event.stopPropagation` or `return false;`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301652/delegated-event-binding-in-jquery/39301740#39301740 for an explanation of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
$("#top10ItemsTable").click(function () {
     alert('you clicked inside the Top 10 Items quadrant table');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).on("click", "#top10ItemsTable", function () {

    alert('you clicked inside the Top 10 Items quadrant table');

})
```

Final code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
      <table id="top10ItemsTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Item Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="rightjustifytext">Qty</th>
    </tr>
        </table>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
           

    
$(document).on("click", "#top10ItemsTable", function () {
    
    alert('you clicked inside the Top 10 Items quadrant table');
        
})     
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```