# jQuery, "on" delegation on link not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the delegated on event, but I can't only on links.
Here is my code, for example:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}" class="jQueryLoad">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i>
        Dashboard
    </a>
</li>
```

If I do in my app's JS file (with this I get the alert):

```
$('.jQueryLoad').on('click', function(){
    alert("test");
    return false;
});
```

But, if I use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".jQueryLoad", function(){
    alert("test");
    return false;
});
```

I never get the "test" alert, the link is just loading as it should if no JS was applied to it.

Am I missing something? I read that I should put more "specific" selector than `document`, but I can't. I have many links, located in different parts of the website.

Thanks,
Sreadon

Comment: Not possible to say without seeing a [mcve]. The apparent tendency to add `return false` at the end suggests that some other event handler applies and stops the click event propagation before it reaches `document`.

Comment: as JJJ said the problem probably lies in other parts of your code and we need them to answer

Comment: If you have a click handler in some element between `.jQueryLoad` and the root, and it does `event.stopPropagation()`, it will prevent delegation from working.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301652/delegated-event-binding-in-jquery/39301740#39301740 for an explanation of that issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it! I'm using an "accordeon" static menu, and dynamic content on the other hand, so on the static menu, I'll stay with non delegation functions, and on the dynamic one, I'll use delegation as it's not in the menu.

Thanks again, I was starting to become crazy..