# datatables responseive and registering a click on a link in a cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have datatables with responsive set to true.

And also in every row I have a link that I should call a function when clicked ( registered in document ready `$('a.here').click(...)`).

Issue is that it works great when I have normal window (not responsive part).
When I resize a window (or view the page on mobile) and the responsive part kicks in the click is not registered and the default action (going to '#') triggers.

How can I register the function to work on clicking in each scenario?

Comment: If the data is being reloaded when the responsive UI is triggered then you will need to use a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: Why don't you check the click on the cell itself instead of putting a link inside?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OK, do you have more info about that, or should I google the "delegated event handler" as I have no clue what that means.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Because I have other links in that cell, and also when datatables go into responsive mode it converts cells that would be off screen into a extending row.

Comment: This might help you understand delegating handlers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301652/delegated-event-binding-in-jquery

Comment: There is a simple DataTables example [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender#Examples) - see the second code fragment. The context is slightly different from yours (it uses `"deferRender": true`, which you do not need`) - but the same principle applies.

Comment: This page may provide a better explanation in the context of DataTables: [DOM / jQuery events](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html).